# How does ASP.NET webservices route requests do WebMethods?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ipc

I'm having problems because of a poorly written third-party library which our system heavily depends on. This library is not thread-safe (because of some bugs and static variables) and I need to use it in a ASP.NET webservice, which handles each user request in a separate thread.

I've tried many solutions for this problem. The best solution for now is, in my opinion, let subprocesses handle the requests. One subprocess will listen and handle the requests for one user, so I can synchronize access to the library code in a per user fashion, which is much better than all that I can do when sharing static variables between requests.

How can I route requests received by IPC communication to the appropriate WebMethods without reinventing the wheel? If possible, I would like to use the classes from .Net that handle this in a normal ASP.NET webservice, but I'm having a hard time trying to find their names.

**TL;DR**: I have a class MyWebService (that inherits from System.Web.Services.WebService) with some methods marked with WebMethodAttribute and I want to pass a made-up HttpRequest (or HttpContext) to it and tell it "handle it like you're receiving this from a real HTTP server, despite the fact the current process is a console application".

Comment: I've realized that if I can start an ASP.NET WebService programatically and make it listen to a specific port (or handle request to a specific path) it will achieve the same. But if we have 30 users there will be 30 webservices running in IIS, which could be much more overhead than the subprocess approach. Also, this approach seems to be less secure.

Comment: ASMX does not give you control over hosting or listening. WCF does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you may want to consider using WCF instead of ASMX, which is a legacy technology, kept only for backwards compatibility.

Second, you have another option: ensure that only a single thread ever uses the third-party libarary at a time. Placing `lock` blocks around all access to the third-party library may solve the problem.

Comment: I've tried the lock strategy. Ensuring that "only a single thread ever uses the third-party libarary at a time" would imply that only one thread executes at the server at a time.

Comment: About ASMX and WCF, we still use .Net 2.0 framework and migrating to a newer version isn't possible right now. Also, how could WCF help me solve the not-through-web-WebService-acess problem?

Comment: Were you aware that .NET 3.5 is nothing more than .NET 2.0 SP2 is some additional assemblies? Upgrading is much less of a practical problem than you may think. WCF would help because it gives you complete control over the dispatch of incoming requests. You could fairly easily dispatch each incoming request to execute in one of a pool of AppDomains. Each would have its own copy of the statics used by the third party code.

Comment: I agree that WCF fits perfectly. However, I've said "migrating to a newer version isn't possible right now" because we already decided to skip 3.5 and migrate newer products to .Net 4.0, but this isn't a priority now. I think that convincing the others to migrate it to WCF **and** 4.0 will be hard, especially considering the deadline of this task, but I'll give it a try. Or I can simply hack my own request to method call router, what I was trying to avoid when posted this question. I think this will take less time and will interfere with less existing code, but will be less mantainable.

Comment: Thanks for the AppDomain pool suggestion. I didn't know that creating AppDomains was possible. I'll use them instead of processes.